# API で一定時間後に非同期処理を行うベストプラクティス

Tags: php, aws, fuelphp, aws-lambda

EC2 で動いてる Fuel API サーバーで
ユーザからリクエストが来た後一定時間経過後に処理(RDS上のMySQLを更新)というようなことがやりたいです
ただ API なのでユーザにはすぐに返答を返す必要があるため
非同期で処理をしたいのですがそういう機能はあったりしますか？
単に PHP で fork とか thread とかで分岐してしまえばいいのでしょうか

あと Fuel で単独でできない場合 AWS のサービスでタイマー実行を低コストで簡単に行えるものはないですか？

使ったことがあるのが EC2,  Lambda,  API Gateway ぐらいなので
API Gateway 経由で Lambda を起動して Lambda 内で一定時間 sleep してから処理をする
ぐらいしか思いつかないんですが

非同期タイマー処理を行ういい方法があれば教えていただきたいです

## 追記

リクエストを受けてから例えば 5 分後に処理を行いたくて
パラメータをどこかにためておいて
5 分ごとに cron で一斉処理だと
リクエストから 2 分だったり 3 分だったりで処理されるのでNGです

## 追記

さらに終了時の MySQL の状態に応じて能動的にサーバーからユーザにアクションを行いたいので
単に制限時間を MySQL に覚えておいて次にリクエストにきたときに
時間切れかどうかを判定するみたいなこともできません
とにかく「非同期で一定時間後に処理を行う」ということがしたいです

Comment: SQSに積んで定期的にcronから読みに行く、とかはいかがでしょうか

Comment: cronを使うなら、「リクエストを受けたら時間も一緒にキューとして貯める」「cronのタスクで一定時間(=5分)より古いタスクを処理してキューから削除」という方法も考えられます。cronの実行頻度によっては逆に遅延が発生するケースも出てきますが。

Comment: どこまで厳密なタイマー処理が必要ですか？例えば1secも1msもずれては行けないだとCronや単一デーモンでやることは難しく、キュー単位でサービスを立ち上げる必要がありそうです。1分以内であればどれほどの処理を行うかによりますが、複数デーモンや複数Cronでなんとかできるかもしれないですね。

Comment: あとは前倒しと遅延をどこまで許容できるかの要件もあれば、合わせて追記してください。

Comment: 1msもずれてはいけないということはないと思いますが、ゲームの制限時間管理なので１秒もずれるのはダメだと思います（どうしても無理なら要件確認しますが）。とりあえず Lambda なり fork なりで分岐して sleep して時間になったら MySQL を更新するみたいなことをすれば可能だと思うんですが、そういう非同期ジョブに特化したライブラリやサービスがあれば教えてほしいという感じでした